# How to exploit XSS and SQL injection via HTTP verb tampering?

Tags: xss, http, sql-injection

I was reading a paper about 'HTTP verb tampering' here:
https://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2008/06/what-you-need-to-know-about-http-verb.html

The author said:

> 2. HTTP verb tampering is generally used in conjunction with syntactic
>    (XSS, SQLi, etc.) and semantic (bypass authentication/authorization
>    controls) attacks as way to bypass certain defense measures. Arshan’s
>    work on implementation details focus on the semantic version.

Can anyone give me an example about how we can exploit an SQL injection and XSS via HTTP verb tampering?

I don't understand the next example in the same paper about this.

Comment: The example simply says to launch the injection attack using another verb other than `GET`.

Comment: @schroeder , but how it make a different ? i still dont understand , can you explain it to me please ?

Comment: It explains it: "A config might say HTTP requests to the /admin/* directory using “GET” must have an “admin” session role. One would ASSUME any methods not listed (POST, HEAD, WHATEVER) in the config would automatically be placed in default-deny mode, but this is not necessarily the case."

Comment: Here's a link to an explanation of how a simple mis-configuration in a framework (ASP.NET here) can lead to the vulnerability: https://www.sans.org/blog/http-verb-tampering-in-asp-net/  (One thing they don't explain is that routing can sometimes be setup so that it's "page-controller_name\method_name"... it doesn't take into account the verb at all... so if it bypasses the security the method would still be called.... other routing schemes use methods based on verb so the call would go nowhere)

Answer (score 1):

The term "HTTP verb tampering" sounds much more exotic and blog-title-worthy than what it's actually talking about. The attack is really simple, and like many vulnerabilities, is the sort of thing it seems crazy anybody would get wrong... but people do.

Suppose you have a webapp that takes some user input at a specific path, `/user_input`. Normally, perhaps requests are sent to that path via POST request. Somebody noticed that there was a risk of XSS or similar, so they wanted to add a security check to the endpoint. They added a POST request handler which runs before the main logic for the path. This POST request handler takes the request body and performs input validation, ensuring that there's nothing in there that could cause XSS (or any other injection attacks, such as SQLi, command injection, LDAP injection, etc.). Fine, so long as you only send requests to the page using POST. But what if you use GET (moving the parameters from the body to the query string)? Then you bypass the POST-specific validation step, but possibly still hit the logic that takes the page parameters (which the webapp framework will helpfully extract from either query string or request body), and thus you can create a link that triggers an XSS attack. Or maybe there's a server-side injection attack, like SQLi or command injection, and maybe GET doesn't work because GET does some different logic (or maybe the injection-vulnerable parameters can only be supplied in the request body). But if you change the verb to PUT or PATCH or some such, then it again bypasses the POST-specific validation, but you can still supply a request body and the server still executes the default logic for that endpoint, extracting the parameters from the body and using them unsafely.

**TL;DR:** The so-called "verb tampering" is simply the operation of changing GET to POST, or POST to GET, or either one to HEAD, or to PUT/PATCH/whatever, and possibly moving parameters from query string to body or vice versa. The reason it works as an attack is that sometimes this lets you skip validation or escaping logic while still hitting a path vulnerable to injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

People create brilliant but also crazy applications.

SQL injection through HTTP Verb tampering is not something I have encountered, but I could imagine a really bad logging script that aims to store HTTP request metadata and uses the verb without any sanitizing.

One example of XSS I have seen was the server reporting that a certain verb was unknown/not implemented by rendering the used verb directly. A nice `<SCRIPT> / HTTP/1.1` request could be used as proof of concept. This server responded neatly with `The method <SCRIPT> is not implemented`.

Now, generally, it is my belief that verb tampering vulnerabilities are generally concerning authorization bypasses. However, they are used-controlled input, so you can make your software stupid enough to be vulnerable for anything!